# For a given day, how to get the last day of the month that comes after the quarter end month

Tags: java

I am trying to get the last day of the month that comes after the quarter end month for a give date.

For eg: if the input date is April 15, 2024, the quarter is Q2 and quarter end date is Jun 30, 2024.
The expected output is July 31, 2024.

The following gives quarter end date

```
var parsedStartDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDate lastDayOfQuarter = parsedStartDate.withMonth(parsedStartDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR) * 3).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
LocalDate targetSlaDate = lastDayOfQuarter.plusMonths(1);
```

Comment: Plus 2 months minus 1 day?

Comment: Without an external library I suggest that this is the natural way: `LocalDate.parse("2024-04-15") .plus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS) .with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1) .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())`. Gives `2024-07-31`. There is a slight detour in it in that I first go into the next quarter, then to *the first day* of that quarter and finally to the end of the month. I like that we don’t have to do any math ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do it but this works and corrects for the proper days of the month.  The methods are described in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html)

- taking the remainder divided by 12 wraps around correctly for the next year.

```
var parsedStartDate = LocalDate.parse(startDate,
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDate lastDayOfQuarter = parsedStartDate
        .withMonth(parsedStartDate.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR) * 3)
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Days adjustment starts here

```
int days = Month.of((lastDayOfQuarter.getMonthValue() + 1) % 12)
        .maxLength();

LocalDate targetSlaDate = lastDayOfQuarter.plusDays(days);
```

Comment: Nice shot. Preferring not to do the math ourselves allow me to suggest `LocalDate.parse(startDate) .plus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS) .with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1) .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())` (feel free to use in your answer if you see fir).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

To get the last day of the first month that follows the quarter of a specific date:

```java
YearMonth.from(
    org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter
    .from( 
        LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.APRIL , 15 )
    )
    .plusQuarters( 1 )
    .atDay( 1 )
)
.atEndOfMonth()
```

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

[*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) is a library that extends the functionality of the *java.time* classes in Java 8+ as defined in JSR 310.

That library offers the [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class.

Get the current quarter. Specify a time zone because for any given moment **the date varies** around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
YearQuarter currentQuarter = YearQuarter.now( z ) ;
```

Get the quarter for a date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.APRIL , 15 ) ;
YearQuarter q = YearQuarter.from( ld ) ;
```

You seem to want the first month after that quarter. The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents the entirety of a specific month.

```
YearQuarter quarterAfter = q.plusQuarters( 1 ) ;
LocalDate firstDayOfQuarterAfter = quarterAfter.atDay( 1 ) ;
YearMonth month = YearMonth.from( firstDayOfQuarterAfter ) ;
```

Get the [last day of that month](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth()).

```
LocalDate lastDayOfMonth = month.atEndOfMonth() ;
```